# Settling time is not displaying on the step response graph

Tags: matlab, transfer-function

I am graphing the step response of a closed loop system and I need to display the settling time on the graph for my assignment. Here is my code:

```
s = tf('s')
L = (20*(s+1))/(10*s*(s-1))
T = L/(1+L)
step(T)
```

Normally, I would just right click on the graph and in the characteristics hit the settling time option and it displays. It isn't displaying anything. I added this line:

```
stepinfo(T)
```

And it gives me the correct step response that is within the bounds of the graph.

Anyone know how to fix it so I can just right click and have it displayed?

Answer (score 1):

The system is unstable, there is a pole in +1.

```
>> isstable(T)

ans =

  logical

   0

>> pole(T)

ans =

   0.0000 + 0.0000i
  -0.5000 + 1.3229i
  -0.5000 - 1.3229i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i
```

so according to [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/dynamicsystem.stepinfo.html;jsessionid=3d4d9162a7785140dcb4eb38dee1) :

> If sys is unstable, then all step-response characteristics are NaN, except for Peak and PeakTime, which are Inf.

It is weird that stepinfo(T) does output a setlling time though, as it shouldn't.

Comment: Shouldn't the closed loop system have a settling time though? L is the open loop and T is the closed

Comment: The closed loop system is the unstable system.

Comment: s = tf('s');
L = (20*(s+1))/(10*s*(s-1));
T = L/(1+L);
[y, t] = step(T);
s_info = stepinfo(T);
figure;
plot(t, y);
hold on;
line([s_info.SettlingTime s_info.SettlingTime], [0 1], 'Color', 'red', 'LineStyle', '--');
hold off;
xlabel('Time (sec)');
ylabel('Output');
title('Step Response of Closed-loop System');
legend('Step Response', 'Settling Time');

Comment: if I have that it also displays a settling time but just by force

Comment: try `step(T,50)`, and you will see that the system is unstable. So, the settle time has no physical meaning because `yfinal` is infinity.